# Referencing to views inside layout layers in DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, viewgroup, findviewbyid

I have a **parent** layout that has an `<include>` tag to a **header** layout.
This header layout has:

```
 Button                  ImageView  ImageView                   XButton
```

The parent layout also has a container that I load a **content** layout to as a DialogFragment.

I can't seem to find a way to reference the xButton in the **header** layout from within the DialogFragment **content** layout when I load it.

I've tride to use

```
View view = viewgroup.findViewById(R.id.x_button);
```

from within the DialogFragment onCreateView right before `return vew;`, but keeps returning null.

The Question: How can I get the reference of a view that is located in a sub-layout (add as `<include>` tag) from the container's dialog fragment.
[image]

Thank you, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry I'm confused which layout contains what. Some lines of code could help to clarify your situation. Please consider posting a [MCVE]

Comment: Sorry for my lack of clarity. Please let me know if I'm still being unclear.

Comment: Yes, this is much better :) The answer by Ben P.  should work for you

Answer (score 1):

The layout for your `Activity` is separate from the layout for your `DialogFragment`, so you won't (under normal circumstances) be able to fetch a `View` from your activity using `findViewById()` from within your fragment.

However, as long as your dialog fragment is "attached" to an activity, you can get a reference to your activity by calling `getActivity()`. Therefore, you could retrieve a reference to a view in your activity by calling `getActivity().findViewById()`.

You'll be notified that your dialog is attached to an activity by the `onAttach()` lifecycle callback in your fragment.